# Is there a way to cancel upvote on answer / question?

Tags: support, voting

I accidentally upvoted an answer and I was looking for a way to cancel it, but the only thing I can do is downvote. I'm I missing something or this feature is not implemented?

Comment: Hey why the downvote? It's not very intuitive to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Clicking the upvote arrow again will undo the upvote (the same with the downvote arrow and a downvote). However, if you do not undo your up or downvote within 5 minutes after casting it, you cannot undo the vote until or unless the post is edited.

Comment: Guess it's too late now to undo the upvote then... lucky guy.

Answer (score 1):

Click the Upvote image again.

Answer (score 0):

you can click on upvote link again, and if you're quick enough you vote will be canceled. I'm usually not that quick.

Answer (score 0):

If you hover over the upvote or downvote triangle, you will get a tooltip that says "... (click again to undo)"