# Upvoting a downvoted answer will do +2 upvote?

Tags: support, down-votes, up-votes

I have first downvoted an answer. Then, I decided to leave it the way it was before, meaning to undo my downvote just like it never existed, so I upvote to remove my downvote. Suprise! SO seems to consider it as two upvotes!

Let's say I have an answer with -3, then I decide to downvote it making it -4. After deeper thoughts, I prefer to remove my downvote to let it the way it was before I downvoted, meaning -3, but SO makes it -2 automatically!

> Wouldn't it be supposed -3, and not -2? If someone else would have upvoted, it would have made it an upvote +1, not a +2!

Am I missing something here?

In fact, is there a way to tell SO that I only wish to undo my downvote, and not upvote the answer? I may understand why it does behave this way. I only wish to undo my downvote, though.

Comment: Duplicate: "Removing a downvote adds reputation that wasn’t there" at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10984/removing-a-downvote-adds-reputation-that-wasnt-there (by design)

Comment: (As an aside: to *undo* a vote, click the same vote again. Clicking the other vote is not really undoing, but changing.)

Comment: @Arjan - your comment isn't really an aside - it the explanation of the behaviour seen by the OP. To remove a vote click **the same vote arrow** again. To reverse a vote click **the opposite vote arrow**

Comment: @ChrisF, you're right, and I was actually wrong referring to that duplicate, which is another issue.

Comment: So, the duplicates are "Cancel a vote so that the tally goes back to zero and not minus" at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30557/cancel-a-vote-so-that-the-tally-goes-back-to-zero-and-not-minus or "Is there a way to cancel upvote on answer / question?" at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22473/is-there-a-way-to-cancel-upvote-on-answer-question, or ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To *undo* a vote, click the same vote you clicked earlier. See the tooltips for help: *click again to undo*. This will change -1 or +1 into 0 (for *your* vote).

(Clicking the other vote is not really *undoing*, but *changing* -1 into +1, or +1 into -1).