# Bug in downvote/upvote

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, voting

I downvoted an answer on SO:

1. Answer marked as 0 votes
2. Downvoted it as the answer was incorrect, it became -1
3. Then the answer was corrected by a user
4. Elected to upvote it, now at this stage I was expecting it to be 0
5. No, instead it went up to 1

Can anyone explain this....that does not sound correct?

Oh yeah, using Opera 10.10, Win XP w SP3...

P.S: under Opera 10.10, submitting an question to Meta.stackoverflow does not work. Am using IE 8 to do this... sigh

Thanks,
Tom.

Comment: Sure this is a duplicate, but yet again I can't find it.

Comment: @ChrisF (and all), duplicate of "Cancel a vote so that the tally goes back to zero and not minus" at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30557/cancel-a-vote-so-that-the-tally-goes-back-to-zero-and-not-minus, or "Is there a way to cancel upvote on answer / question?" at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22473/is-there-a-way-to-cancel-upvote-on-answer-question, or "Upvoting a downvoted answer will do +2 upvote?" at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40683/upvoting-a-downvoted-answer-will-do-2-upvote, or ... ;-)

Comment: @Arjan, good find. It was the last one I was specifically thinking of.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If *you* were the one who downvoted it, and *you* ended up upvoting it, how can *your own votes* cancel each other out?

For it to end up at 0, you'd have to cancel your downvote (by clicking the down arrow again) rather than changing it to an upvote (by clicking the up arrow).

Comment: Yes, upvoting an answer that has already been downvoted cancels the downvote(0) and applies the upvote(+1).  I know I've read Jeff talk about this behavior before... now, if I can only find where.

Comment: mmyers: Oh....I didn't know that...sigh...Of course to boost your rep whorin, I'll upvote and accept yer answer!.... :p That strangely is not mentioned about it or I have missed it...

Comment: @mmyers: There done it! You should see a nice increase there on your rep! :P lol man...that should have been said somewhere obviously....

Comment: @tommieb75: How exactly is answering your question quickly, correctly and accurately 'rep-whorin'?

Comment: @ire_and_curses: guess it didn't go down too well with others...look I was kidding aside, just trying to inject a bit of light relief....

Comment: sheesh - man...relax...no need to upvote ire_and_curses comment! The handle is saying a lot there...

Comment: Or, like noted in the tooltip: "click again to undo".