# Attempting to zero out a downvote resulted in an upvote

Tags: support, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cancel a vote so that the tally goes back to zero and not minus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30557/cancel-a-vote-so-that-the-tally-goes-back-to-zero-and-not-minus)
>   [Bug in downvote/upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41028/bug-in-downvote-upvote)

There was a response to a question this afternoon which merited a downvote because the initial response was incorrect. However the author edited their solution to an acceptable answer, so I wanted to remove my downvote, by clicking the up arrow, thinking this would zero out the downvote. Instead it removed my downvote then added +1 for an upvote. How should I have zeroed out my downvote without casting an upvote? Just click on the number?

Comment: Click the voting arrow again to undo the vote (check the tooltip on the voting arrows)

Comment: Obviously you don't do enough downvoting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To zero out your downvote, you would merely click on the downvote button again, which would cancel your previous downvote.

If you had passed the time limit for undoing your votes, then you would have been unable to do so, unless the author edited their question as you had mentioned.

Comment: I see. This seems unintuitive, perhaps a red x or something by the downvote to indicate that you wish to remove the downvote. Thanks.

Comment: Not really.  The downvote button glows after you select it.  Naturally, if you click again it should toggle the button's function.  Just my opinion, anyway.

Comment: Ya I see the color change, but didn't think to click it again to remove the downvote.

Comment: @DigitalPrecision: there's even a tooltip that tells you what to do to undo your vote.

Comment: @Mat: Still doesn't change the fact that it is confusing user experience to have someone click the downvote arrow again to cancel a vote. But I know now, thanks.