# I just clicked to vote a question up, but it reduced to zero instead (superuser)

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting

I just clicked to vote [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/118946/why-is-there-an-auto-connect-delay-to-a-hidden-wireless-network-ubuntu-9-10) up, but the number decreased to zero instead. When I tried to vote it up a second time, it said my vote was too old to be changed.

Has anyone else run into this?

Additional clarifications:

Prior to yesterday, I had never cast any vote on the question one way or another nor attempted to do so. When I visited the question yesterday, it had a "score" of +1. I attempted to upvote the question by clicking on the up arrow. When I did this, the score reduced to zero. Then I clicked it a second time and it gave the "Vote too old to be changed" error.

In fact if I go there right now, the score is zero and if I click the up or down arrow it gives the "too old to be changed" error. This would imply that I've voted, yet some folks  with the reputation to see the individual up/down votes are saying that the question indicates that it's received no votes at all (up or down).

Furthermore, poor Joe Casadonte (author of the question) now has a -50 reputation associated with that question (if you go look at his reputation tab).

Lastly, I happened to have another browser window opened to the same question prior to this incident. When it happened, I saw his rep score go down. I would have though I was seeing things had I not had the other window still open with the higher rep score.

Comment: Is any of the up or down arrows highlighted for you? (If neither is blue, then you probably undid your own vote, like balpha answered.)

Comment: I add further clarification/detail to the question. Thanks.

Comment: So I guess the next question is, can you duplicate the problem?

Comment: The -50 is for the bounty (which *you* received, plus 50 from Stack Overflow). As for the up/down see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22473/is-there-a-way-to-cancel-upvote-on-answer-question And what about my first comment, about one of the arrows being blue -- or not?

Comment: @Arjan: No, neither arrow is blue.

Comment: If neither is coloured, then no vote is currently registered for you. But as you're also being told your vote is too old to be changed, the system knows you did vote at some point in time. Hence, really the only explanation is that you clicked the upvote twice and undid your own vote, like both balpha and khat-formerly-known-as-Jonathan answered. No worries, you're not the first to do this by mistake.

Comment: @The developers: I'd like to suggest a modification of the system whereby in order to "undo" a vote, you have to click on the opposite vote (e.g. click down if you had clicked up, or up if you had clicked down). This might prevent this issue in the future.

Comment: @MT, that would be another question/feature request? (I foresee some problems with the time lock; one would have to click twice then to change +1 into -1, and the time lock might prevent the second click.)

Answer (score 4):

Is it possible you had voted on the question before? Clicking the up arrow on a question that you already upvoted will undo the upvote, so the click results in a score loss of 1, just as you observed.

And according to the [timeline of this question](https://superuser.com/posts/118946/timeline)*, there's no other vote that has been cast on this question, so if you saw a score of "1" on the question before you clicked the arrow, it's very like that this was your own vote.

<sub>* I don't have 1000 rep on SU to look at the split</sub>

Comment: The split is currently 0/0.

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson: Thanks. That concurs with the timeline (it's just that the timeline seems to be having some vote count bugs, so I don't trust it as far as the split).

Comment: @psubsee2003 They do. But this answer is from March of 2010, which was before I joined the company.

Answer (score 2):

Might you have accidentally double-clicked the vote button instead of single-clicking it? This would quickly set/unset a vote, which cannot be undone unless the post is edited in some way.

Answer (score 1):

With realtime updates - this can no longer happen in a modern browser.  balpha's answer is correct - you upvoted and un-upvoted the same question.  With realtime, you would now be aware of the score changes even in a separate browser window.