# Cancel Vote (Up Vote/Down Vote)

Tags: feature-request, voting

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Cancel a vote so that the tally goes back to zero and not minus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30557/cancel-a-vote-so-that-the-tally-goes-back-to-zero-and-not-minus)

Hello all,

My Stackoverflow profile: https://stackoverflow.com/users/379693/pm-paresh-mayani

As i am using a Stackoveflow since last few months, i have noted one thing:
Consider, You are reading a question/answer and if you impressed/depressed then you are going to do upvote/downvote accordingly to that question or answer.

But later on , if we came to know that the question or answer is in wrong direction or meaningless than we need to cancel our voting that we have given on that Question/Answer.

[image][image]

Check the attached images, i have upvoted an answer once, later on i supposed to cancel my vote so i pressed Downvote, it should Cancel of your vote (0 instead of -1) on first click on Downvote, what you say ??

So what if we want to cancel our Voting given on the particular Question/Answer??

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30557/cancel-a-vote-so-that-the-tally-goes-back-to-zero-and-not-minus — @closevoters: I pasted the wrong url — use 30557 (the one i've linked to) instead

Comment: Or http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22473/is-there-a-way-to-cancel-upvote-on-answer-question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to just click on the UpVote again to cancel. These votes work in a toggle mode. You click once, you upvote, you click the same again, it cancels your upvote.