# Bug with upvoting by mistake?

Tags: support, voting

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Cancel Vote (Up Vote/Down Vote)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71885/cancel-vote-up-vote-down-vote)
>   [Cancel a vote so that the tally goes back to zero and not minus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30557/cancel-a-vote-so-that-the-tally-goes-back-to-zero-and-not-minus)

I was reading a question and I accidentally upvoted an answer by mistake (i wanted the answer below it). The answer already had 1 up vote so when I upvoted it went to 2. I realized I made a mistake and then down voted to take away my vote for that answer. BUT, the votes went to 0 instead of 1 and I was penalized points for down voting and of course the user who posted the answer now has -2 points.

Is this a bug or did I do it wrong?

Comment: FYI, the tooltip text is pretty helpful here, there's a "(click again to undo)" in there which would have guided you the right way.  SO in general is fairly good with mouseover tooltips, so when in doubt, check those out.

Answer (score 6):

You click on the upvote arrow to remove it.  What happened is by design.  Clicking on the down arrow changes your vote to a downvote.