# How can I cancel my vote?

Tags: support, voting, cancel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any voting limits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/are-there-any-voting-limits)
>   [Cancel a vote so that the tally goes back to zero and not minus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30557/cancel-a-vote-so-that-the-tally-goes-back-to-zero-and-not-minus)
>   [Cancel Vote (Up Vote/Down Vote)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71885/cancel-vote-up-vote-down-vote)

Is it possible to cancel vote?

Suppose I voted on a question. But later I realise that this question does not deserve vote. So how can I cancel my vote?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you simply click the arrow again.

That is, to remove an upvote, click the up arrow and to remove a downvote click the down arrow. You should already see it highlighted — clicking again will remove the vote and highlight.

[image: Upvote button selected]

However, there is a time limit on this. You only have about 5 minutes in which to change your mind unless the question or answer has been edited in the meantime. This is to prevent gaming of the system whereby you down-vote all competing answers and then when your answer is accepted or clearly ahead in votes revoke the down-votes.

Comment: @ACoder Remember to accept the answer when you receive a solution to your problem. :)

Comment: There should be no time limit on this.  We can change our minds at any time, so we should be able to change our votes at any time.

Comment: I agree.  Sometimes you discover why something that sounded good doesn't work.  There could be limits, but I don't think it should be by time.  Maybe lock off (or put back the 5-minute clock) if a user is doing it a lot.  The cancel vote could also give a confirm dialog mentioning the concern Oded described, and asking not to do that (relying on honesty.)

Comment: That's really bad.
I was wrong when downvoted and author explained me in comment that I'm wrong and answer is correct.(

Answer (score 3):

If you realise it soon enough, you can simply remove your vote by clicking the arrow again. If it is too late for that, you can remove your vote only after the question has been edited.

Comment: Since voting how long my vote is not registered?

Comment: It is registered immediately, after - I think - five minutes, your vote is locked and then can be changed only after an edit.